# Multiple docker services to listen on same host and port

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, microservices, jwilder-nginx-proxy

i am new to nginx and I am not sure is this normal behavior...

Here is the lib I am using: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

I will explain here what I trying to accomplish...

I have 2 additional services `service1` and `service2` those services are simple node.js images with API endpoints

```
service1 have routes:
- service1/api/first
- service1/api/second
`

`
service2 have routes:
- service2/api/third
- service2/api/fourth
`

So is possible to be able to access this services from same host, like this:
localhost/service1/api/first
localhost/service2/api/third
?

I tried like this:

My `docker-compose.yml` file:


version: '2'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.local
  service1:
    image: mynode:1.1
    volumes:
        - .:/app
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=service1.local
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
  service2:
    image: mynodeother:1.2
    volumes:
        - .:/app
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=service2.local
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8081
```

Here is generated config file from command `docker exec nginx-proxy cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`:
http://pushsc.com/show/code/58f739790a58d602a0b99d22

Also when I visit localhost in browser I get:

> Welcome to nginx!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed
>   and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
>   Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
>
> Thank you for using nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use IP addresses inside `nginx` config file. 
Also, you should use the same port number for both services: 8080 (if this is the port that nodejs application is listening).

Then you should properly define your routes to each service using `location` in each `server` context.

So, you should modify `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` inside `nginx` container like this:

```
# service1.local
upstream service1.local {
            ## Can be connect with "nginxproxy_default" network
            # nginxproxy_service1_1
            server service1:8080;
}

server {
    server_name service1.local;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    location /service1 { #note this line
        proxy_pass http://service1.local;
    }
}

# service2.local
upstream service2.local {
            ## Can be connect with "nginxproxy_default" network
            # nginxproxy_service2_1
            server service2:8080; #same port
}

server {
    server_name service2.local;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    location /service2 { #note this line
        proxy_pass http://service2.local;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this lib: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy to generate nginx config file... Do you know why it create worng conf?

Comment: From what I see, this is used to proxy by subdomains, not by path

Comment: @Vladimir It means you can't use this tool

Comment: Tried your solution also but not working it will return just route from frist service but cannot access route from sercond service...

Comment: @Vladimir send me your cofinguration file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142102/discussion-between-constantin-galbenu-and-vladimir).