# Using Nginx(dockerise) to point to two different docker services with same port but different location directives

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, microservices

```
upstream engine.app {
    server engine:8000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name engine.app;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://engine.app;
        proxy_set_header Host "localhost";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

upstream parser.app {
    server parser:8000;
}
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name parser.app;
   location /parser {
       proxy_pass http://parser.app;
       proxy_set_header Host "localhost";
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_redirect off;
   }
}
```

Given this nginx config

I am unable to expose parser service at `server_ip/parser` while `server_ip/engine` and `server_ip/engine/route1` works.

I have two docker services `parser:8000` and `engine:8000`. And eventually I would like to expose the parser:8000 service to internet same as did for engine.

Please advise.

References:

1. [Similar Case 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492974/multiple-docker-services-to-listen-on-same-host-and-port?rq=4)

Comment: What URL(s) are you trying to call, from where, and what result to you get?  It looks like you're running two separate `server` blocks; does the setup work better if there is only one?

Comment: Also, do you expect the `parser` part of the URL to be passed on to the parser.app container or should it be removed?

Comment: @DavidMaze i tried to put this in one server as well but in vain.

Comment: @HansKilian both services are FastAPI web apps. so i am expecting /parser to proxy this path to parser api routes such as `/` or `/url/` etc

Comment: Your `location` should be `/parser/` (with a trailing slash) for Nginx to strip `parser` from the URL that's passed to the web app.

Answer (score 0):

```
upstream parser.app {
    server parser:8000;
}
upstream engine.app {
    server engine:8000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name engine;
     location / {
        proxy_pass http://engine.app/;
        proxy_set_header Host "localhost";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    location /parser/ {
        proxy_pass http://parser.app/;
        proxy_set_header Host "localhost";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

adding trailing `/` in proxy pass address worked. (while keeping only one server.)

**Hints by David and Hans**